# In c++, how to traslate a point attached to another in 3D space according to the latest one's quaternion rotations

Tags: c++, rotation, quaternions

I have to possitions, p1 and p2, p2 is attached to p1, not only to p1's position but also to it's rotation, so q1 is a quaternion which represents p1's rotation.
If q1 rotates, then p1's position must also rotate around p1 accordingly.
I only need to calculate p2's position, not it's rotation, I worked the rotation out already.
So basically is a spaceship docked to a station, I need to move and rotate the station around with the ship docked to it.
How do I do it?

the code i wrote for it works as long as the station is not rotated during the time of docking:

```
bool docked[100];
Quaternion quatTarget[100];
double distance_dock[100];

vector3 docking_position(int ship, int station)
{
    if (!docked[ship])
    {
        docked[ship] = true;
        distance_dock[ship] = distances(position[ship], position[station]);
        vector3 direcc = normalized(position[station] - position[ship]);
        quatTarget[ship] = vecToVecRotation(direcc, { 0, 0, 1 });
        QuaternionNormalize(&quatTarget[ship], &quatTarget[ship]);
    }

    Quaternion orientation = total_rotation[station] * quatTarget[ship];

    Matrix docking_place;

    MatrixRotationQuaternion(&docking_place, &orientation);

    vector3 axis_z = { docking_place(0, 2), docking_place(1, 2), docking_place(2, 2) };

    return position[station] + -axis_z * distance_dock[ship];
}
```

What I do here is take an orientation quaternion from the ship to the station at the time of docking and then traslate the ship "distance_dock" units along the negative z axis of the orientation, so the ship will always move accordingly, but somehow if I dock the ship when the station is already rotated then I get the initial docking position wrong, though it still rotates perfectly along with the station.

Comment: Any code you have written to try to solve this issue?

Comment: yeah, just posted it, don't know if it's understandable though

Comment: All you want to do is rotate the vector from the station to the ship, `(p2 - p1)`, whenever you rotate the station. Then the ship's position is just the position of the station plus the rotated vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have two objects that have a rigid transformation between them. The problem is that you want to calculate the pose (position + orientation) of one, given the pose of the other.

Let's say you have three frames; the Station frame "S", the Vehicle frame "V" and the Global frame "G" (I assume your graphics environment has a global 3D Cartesian frame).
The transformation between frames S and V is fully known (translation and orientation) and constant, and is denoted S_p_SV (the position of the Vehicle w.r.t the Station, expressed in the Station frame) and SV_q (the quaternion orientation of the Vehicle, expressed in the Station frame).

This will be confusing if you have not had experience in rigid-body mechanics, in which case you should read some introductory notes/slideshows on *"Rigid-Body Mechanics"* which are plentiful on Google results.

I have written the expression in LATEX but unfortunately StackOverflow does not support it, so I have attached it as an image. The original LATEX can be found [here](http://www.texpaste.com/n/cad2qmov).
In my notation below, for example on the first line **Sp_SV** , is the **p**osition of the **V**ehicle w.r.t. the **S**tation, expressed in the **S**tation frame (of rotation).
The prefixed superscript indicates the rotation frame. For the quaternion **G_Sq** for example, this represents the orientation of the **S**tation frame from the **G**round Frame.

[image: LATEX Of the 2-particle rigid transform]

In terms of implementing this in C++, I am unsure of what library you are using for Quaternions, but you will need the following functions:

- Convert Euler to Quaternions - If you are going to manually specify the rotation SV**q** (rotation of Vehicle w.r.t Station)
- Convert Quaternion to DCM - For the first method in the LATEX
- Quaternion Multiply - For the second method in the LATEX
- Quaternion Conjugate - For the second method in the LATEX

Comment: now that's what I call a good answer! Thanks buddy. I'll let you know how it goes for my program as soon as I get back to it.