# How to synchronize the position of two points with the same orientation represented in quaternion?

Tags: translate, quaternions

I have two points with fixed distance (e.g. 30 centimeter) and exactly the same orientation in 3D space. The position of point 1 (x1,y1,z1) and orientation of point 1 (represented in quaternion q0, q1, q2, q3) are already known. How can I calculate the position of point 2 ? (No matter how I move them, the distance between them won't change and the orientation will always be the same)

I searched on the web, and this is the closest question I can find https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/173480-Calculate-object-orientation-from-a-quaternion but I still could not figure out how to solve it. I guess I didn't define the problem correctly so that I'm not able to find the right mathmatical solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood of your question you have two particles P1 and P2 that have a *rigid transformation* between them (at all times the relative position and relative orientation between P1 and P2 are constant).

[image: Rigid Body Mechanics 2D Animation]

The answer is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537160/in-c-how-to-traslate-a-point-attached-to-another-in-3d-space-according-to-the/27923938) however it is a bit different.

Lets say your two particle positions are p1 and p2, and the rotation of the first particle is q1 = [w1, x1, y1, z1].
The relative quaternion orientation between P1 and P2 is **q12** and the relative position is **p12** = **p2** - **p1**. Then:

```
p2 = p1 + C(q1)*p12
q2 = q1 ⊗ q12
```

Where ⊗ is the quaternion multiplication operator, and C(**q1**) is the rotation matrix formed from **q1**. See the link I posted above for how to do this without the C(**q**) function.

For funsies, the position and orientation of any particle P3 with a rigid transform between P2 is very similar:

```
p3 = p2 + C(q2)*p23
q3 = q2 ⊗ q23
```

EDIT: I've added a figure and animation to try and explain the relative position and orientations, although it is hard to do, so I have shown only the 2D case which has only (x, y) and rotation about the z axis. The same concept applies to 3d but it is harder to visualise.

You must know the relative position between P1 and P2 *expressed in the parent frame*, as well as the relative orientation. Or you can work those out by knowing the initial positions and orientations of each particle *in the Global frame*, but this is more difficult with quaternions. The relative positions are fairly straightforward, but the orientations require a bit of effort. First find the Euler angle rotation sequence that brings P1 axes into alignment with the P2 axes. Then use some library to convert the Euler->quaternion.

[image: Rigid Body Mechanics 2D Illustration]

Comment: Thanks for your time @Gouda ! I don't quite understand p12 which is the relative position of p1 and p2. Is it constant or non-constant? Is this similar to the constant offset sP(sv) from station frame to vehicle frame in the other question? in my case only the distance between the two points is fixed. Imagine the two points are attached to two sides of a stick. If I move, rotate the stick, the relative position seems to change depending on p1's rotation.

Comment: The equations I've written are called the 'rigid-body mechanics' equations and apply to the scenario you describe (separated by a stick). p12 is the position of P2 as measured **from** P1, i.e. a vector with the length of the stick, in the direction of P2. Keep in mind that P1 (and P2..3..etc) has its own axes which defines its orientation; p12 is measured in this frame, not the global frame. In other words, p12 can be expressed in the P1 frame as (for example) p12=[1,2,0], and also in the global frame as p12=[1,0,2] (for some orientation).

Comment: Now I got what p12 should look like. Thank you for the explanation! Could you also specify **how** to calculate p12 ? (given only q1, the distance d,  and q1=q2)  Quaternion is new to me and not easy to visualize.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gouda ~ As soon as I figured out p12, the formula works perfectly! I really appreciated your time, effort and fantastic visualization.

Comment: Glad to hear it works for you.
 Could you please accept and upvote the answer so this appears in the search results for future people with the same question. (I've answered the same question 3 times but it's been removed by the garbage collection).

Comment: That's the first thing I tried to do. But the system requires 15 reputation to upvote. Sorry I don't have that much reputation .